# Changing suffix on bash file backup

Tags: linux, bash, suffix

I have been trying to change the suffix on my backup files using the `--suffix` function but I'm not quite sure how to do it. Currently this line of code

```
find ./$1 -name "IMG_****.JPG" -exec cp --backup=t {} ./$2 \;
```

searches the first command line argument directory for images in the `IMG_****.JPG` format and copies them to the directory entered second, making copies of any files with duplicate names and adding the `=t` suffix to the end giving `IMG_****.JPG.~1~` etc. Instead of `.~1~` I would like to add something like `.JPG`, any ideas on how to use the `--suffix` to do this?

Comment: It does not look like --suffix works at all, at least on Ubuntu 15.10

Comment: Ignore that, cp saw that I already had the ~ in there andexisting is the default

Answer (score 5):

Read the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cp):

> The backup suffix is '`~`', unless set with `--suffix` or `SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX`.

It should be pretty obvious from this sentence that supplying `--suffix` is equivalent to setting `SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX`, which as its name suggests only applies to simple backups (i.e., `--backup=simple` or `--backup=never`). E.g.,

```
> touch src dst
> cp --backup=simple --suffix=.bak src dst
> ls src* dst*
dst  dst.bak  src
```

However, you are requesting numbered backups through `--backup=t`, so the suffixes you will get will always be `.~1~`, `.~2~`, etc., unaffected by `--suffix`.